# How to scroll through all available matching interactive (M-x) commands using Helm rather than just my history?

Tags: helm, cycling

I'm using Helm to perform completions for my interactive commands, but it only lets me cycle through those commands which I have used in the past (i.e. 4 Candidate(s)). I don't want this behavior, instead, when pressing C-n/C-p it should cycle across all pattern matched commands. How do I change this behavior?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it only let's you cycle through last used commands? I have latest Helm installed and pressing `C-n` after last history entry correctly moves into the "Emacs commands" section

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`C-o` is bound to `helm-next-source` by default. This will cycle through available sources. In this case, the sources are your command history and available commands.

If you were at the top of your history in the example image, then pressed `C-o`, it'd move you to the first entry in *Emacs Commands*. `C-o` again would move you back to the top of the history.

To move to the command list automatically from the bottom of the history, set `helm-move-to-line-cycle-in-source` to `nil`.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't an answer per se but it might improve the UX to something more of your liking: if you set `helm-mode-reverse-history` to `t` it will put the "Emacs Command History" source after "Emacs Commands".

Or from the Emacs docs themselves:

> Display history source after current source in `helm-mode` handled commands.