# How to add a macro to helm mode tex insert macro?

Tags: helm, latex

I am new to `helm-mode`. When I use it with `LaTeX-mode` for editing TeX files, and type backslash I get the following helm buffer:

[image]

Now, I would like to insert the `\num` command (from the `siunitx` package). However, the command `num` is not recognized, so `nonumber` is selected by default each time, and I then need to press arrow-up to select it and then press enter.

Is there a way to make `num` become the default cadidate? (Assuming I type `num` much more often than `nonumber`)

Alternatively, is there a way to make `TeX-insert-macro History` (see above screen shot) the default helm source instead of the current `TeX-insert-macro`?

Comment: See also [How to scroll through all available matching interactive commands using Helm](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17/how-to-scroll-through-all-available-matching-interactive-m-x-commands-using-he)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make num become the default cadidate? (Assuming I
>   type num much more often than nonumber)

You need to teach `Tex-insert-macro` to know `num`, i.e., add it to the completion collection, it looks like the completion collection is generated by `(TeX-symbol-list-filtered)`. I don't know how since I don't use Tex at all. But it is not related to helm anyway.

> Alternatively, is there a way to make TeX-insert-macro History (see
>   above screen shot) the default helm source instead of the current
>   TeX-insert-macro?

Yes, by setting `helm-mode-reverse-history` to `nil`, the following is its docstring.

```
helm-mode-reverse-history is a variable defined in `helm-mode.el'.
Its value is t

Documentation:
Display history source after current source in `helm-mode' handled commands.

You can customize this variable.
```